# Microsoft 2010 visual c , installing FLTK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fltk

FLTK problems with MSV2010C++

I'm following "Programming - Principles and Practice Using C++".

Having a bad time trying to get FLTK running correctly. I worked for me, once, then never again.
I have detailed the steps taken below, and would really appreciate it if anyone can notice anything strange.

My main concerns are the following:
1) The steps in the Linker > Input > Additional dependencies are a little confusing
2) I have built both solutions for 1.1.9 and 1.3.0. Could these conflict?
3) My understanding of the process is basic to say the least.

What does building actually achieve? What objects will it create? How can I check these have been made correctly?

System
Windows 7(64 bit) (Microsoft 2010 Visual C++)

Steps tried for fltt 1.1.9

1  Download fltk-1.1.9-source

2  The vlC2005 solution gives me the following results:

```
========== Build: 66 succeeded, 3 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

3  Copied the lib files from the source to 
   x:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib

4  Copied the FL FOLDER into (so the folder is added / replaced)
   x:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\

5  If I try to run the solution, it fails -

```
========== Build: 6 succeeded, 3 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

6  Create a new project named graphics6, as a win32 project

7  Application settings - Windows application & empty project

8  In the source files, created graphics6.cpp, added the following code

```
    #include <FL/Fl.h>
    #include <FL/Fl_Box.h>
    #include <FL/Fl_Window.h>

    int main()
    {
    Fl_Window window(200,200,"Window Title");
    Fl_Box box(0,0,200,200,"Hey");
    window.show();
    return Fl::run();
    }
```

9  When I run it, I get the following

```
  1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16  
  referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

10 Alter the project settings - Linker > Input > Additional dependencies:

```
 "kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;
 shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(fltkd.lib
 wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib)"
```

11 When I run, I get this -

```
 1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
_WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

Conclusion
1.1.9 cannot be built under MS2010VC++

Let's try 1.3 instead -------

1  Download 1.3 and run the solution \fltk-1.3.0-source\fltk-1.3.0\ide\VisualC2010\fltk.sln

2  Built it (I've done this a few times, so it gives the following result :

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 79 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

3  If I run it, I get the graphics on the screen. So far so good!

4  Copied the lib files from the source to 
   x:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib

5  Copied the FL FOLDER into (so the folder is added / replaced)
   x:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\

6  Steps 6 - 8 are the same as above, so just loaded the previous project.

7  When I run

```
 1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16
 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
 1>C:my information \visual studio 2010\Projects\graphics6\Debug\graphics6.exe : fatal 
 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

8  added Ignore Default Libraries> libcd.lib

9  Ran it again with the same results

Sorry about the length of this, but I feel the only way to clarify the problem is to include all the details.

As far as I can see, I'm following the instructions as closely as I can. The major problem being that I cant run 1.1.9.

I've searched for solutions to this problem on a number of sites, but have yet to find a detailed step by step write up of the process.

Comment: I think you are looking at wrong thing in your effort to solve this problem. :) I wish I had VC2012 to setup FLTK and give you the answer... Setting up FLTK on Windows was always piece of cake...

Comment: Haha, funny you say that. I'm trying to set it up using MinGw now and failing :) My solution below works for 1.3.0, but not for the previous version. That's my next target. Will post a solution when I have it for others.

Comment: Weird, really, building and using FLTK on MinGW+SYS is a matter of installing autotools... (msysDTK package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLTK 1.3.0

Ok, I've finally gotten a solution to this (after about 12 hours) -

Part 1 - Building FLTK

1. Download fltk-1.3.0 and extract it.
2. Copy the contained fltk-1.3.0 folder to C:\ (you can use another location, but you'll have to change some of the commands).
3. Go into C:\fltk-1.3.0\ide\VisualC2010 and run fltk.sln
4. Right click it and click build
5. It should complete with no errors. If there are errors, I very much doubt this guide will help you.
6. Once it's finished, you should be able to run it (will open windows).

Part 2 - Running your own project
Assuming the build went correctly, you can now follow these steps:

1. Launch MSVC++2010
2. File>New>Project - Select Win32 Project and name

   ```
      FLTK-Test3
   ```
3. Click next on the wizard then 
   Application type: Keep as Windows application
   Additional Options: Empty project
   Click finish
4. Right click source files on the solution explorer, add

   ```
      FLTK-Test3.cpp
   ```
5. Right click FLTK-Test3 and go into properties

   a) Configuration Properties>C/C++>Command Line>Additional Options - add

   ```
       /Ic:\fltk-1.3.0
   ```

   b) Configuration Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies>
   This is the hardest part, you need to add

   ```
       c:\fltk-1.3.0\lib\fltkd.lib;wsock32.lib;comctl32.lib;c:\fltk-1.3.0\lib\fltkjpegd.lib;c:\fltk-1.3.0\lib\fltkimagesd.lib;
   ```

   to the end of the line (replacing the #() information. My change resulted in this, yours might be different -

   ```
     kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;c:\fltk-1.3.0\lib\fltkd.lib;wsock32.lib;comctl32.lib;c:\fltk-1.3.0\lib\fltkjpegd.lib;c:\fltk-1.3.0\lib\fltkimagesd.lib;
   ```

the 'd' at the end of the .lib file indicates debug, so for final build I think you are supposed to include the ones without the 'd'. So ..fltkjpeg.lib not ..jpegd.lib.

If this section works properly, when you add the first #include line of the code, it shouldn't be underlined. If it is, theres a problem.

c) You may also have to do this (if it doesnt run)

Configuration Properties>Linker>Input>Ignore Specific Default Libraries>

```
    libcd.lib
```

1. Once all this has been completed, you should be able to add the full code below -

   ```
   #include <FL/Fl.h>
   #include <FL/Fl_Window.h>

   int main()
   {
    Fl_Window win(320,200);
    win.show();
    return Fl::run();
   }
   ```

Enter the code above, and run.

I still got a ton of errrors, -

```
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FLTK-Test3\Debug\FLTK-Test3.exe', Symbols loaded.
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common- controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimtf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimtf.dll'
  'FLTK-Test3.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
```

.. but it ran!

Hope that helps.

Comment: One problem down, one more to go. I guess 1.3.0 isn't compatible with his header files. I get a ton of errors that I haven't been able to comment out.

Comment: I assume you're on windows 7 or windows vista, to remove these warnings simple run (note : run as administrator) your visual studio

Comment: your file name is .ccp, it suppose to be .cpp ;)

Answer (score 0):

David, I suggest you watch this excellent (after so many years it still rocks) video tutorial made by Greg Ercolano: http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk-videos/fltk-ms-vs-build.html . The video is titled "*How To Get Started Building FLTK With Visual Studio 7.0*" but I believe it is applicable to VC 2010 as well.

About your problem - I think it is simply the type of the project that is perhaps causing the problem... Configure your project to be a Win32 project. Although, FLTK app should work as console app as well...

Comment: Still not working. I've installed MSVC++2010 on a second PC, tried both version. Still nothing. The video is useful, but the system is too different to be sure I'm doing nothing wrong. Without a good understanding of each step in the process, it feels like I'm just taking shots in the dark trying to fix this process. What I really need is an accurate working guide for 2010. Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate the information. I can't wait to get this over so I can get back to programming. My other option is to skip the graphics section entirely, but I think that's gonna be a big mistake.

Comment: At last! I seem to be making some progress now. The link command line was one of the problems. I'll write up a full solution for others as soon as I have it down clearly.

Comment: Well, I am glad to hear that. Sorry I could not help with MS VC - I do not use it for a long time - I prefer using MinGW+MSYS (http://www.mingw.org) to build my applications on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you are getting suggests that probably you have created the project with a setting other than the one is required (Win32 console application) to run FLTK.

The following link should help.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/b83e4884-9dec-4d67-ab92-90d5b6c8c51c/