# Error while compiling ITK/FLTK program in C:\Program Files\FLTK\include\FL\math.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fltk, itk

I want to compile a program using ITK & FLTK in Windows. Visual Studio 2010 shows me the following error:

C:\Program Files\FLTK\include\FL\math.h(22): fatal error C1083:
Cannot open include file: '/usr/include/math.h': No such file or directory

How do I resolve this error? I'm using Windows, not Linux.

Please tell me if any more information is required.

Comment: Build the FLTK library using IDE/vcnet.

Comment: Can you please tell me what IDE/vcnet is? I am new to ITK/FLTK, so sorry if this sounds silly. I actually built ITK, ITKApps and FLTK using ITKApps/superbuild.

Comment: If you download FLTK from the distribution and unzip it, which is what I assume you have done, you will see several directories.  One of them is IDE.  Under IDE, there will be visualc, vcnet, devcpp and cb.  For VS2010, use the solution from vcnet.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357047/microsoft-2010-visual-c-installing-fltk?rq=1